# Row in UITableView isn't deleted immediately

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, uicontextualaction, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I'm using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` `UITableView`'s delegate method for handling when user swipe to delete certain cell (item).

My `UIContextualAction` for *delete event* looks like this. I first remove item from Realm database and then I delete row from my table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { _,_,_ in
        Repository.shared.deleteItem(self.items![indexPath.row])
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
    ...
}
```

But from some reason when I delete cell, it isn't deleted immediately and it returns to position between swipe. Then when I scroll table view, cell disappeared like you can see in gif below:

[image]

I can "fix" this by reloading data of table view right after I remove certain item from database, but this is not what I want to, I want to use `deleteRow(at:with:)` because of animation.

---

One my guess is, that it has something to do with deleting item from Realm database.

I'm deleting item using `delete` method

```
func deleteItem(_ item: Item) {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.delete(item)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

then as data source array for my table view I'm using Realm's `Results`

```
var items: Results<Item>?
```

---

Does anybody have any idea why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: One option is to add a Realm observer to your results dataset. So when you delete an object from realm, your app receives a notification of that event and can update the UI accordingly. It also goes hand-in-hand with adding or editing - the observer closure receives those events and can process them. Keeps the UI fresh and constantly updated.

Comment: Where are you calling `realm.delete`? You only show the code for deleting the table view rows, but don't actually show where you modify the data source.

Comment: @DávidPásztor it's just method which calls `realm.delete(item)` inside *do-try-catch* block

Comment: @Jay okay, that's not bad idea. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried adding `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` before and after you call `deleteRows`?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exactly the issue you had. I'm using Realm too, and I also used `Results<Item>` as my tableView datasource.

My implementation for swipe-to-delete-cell in `tableView(_:, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` method is exactly same as yours: delete the swiped item in `realm.write{}` block, then call `UITableView.deleteRows(at:with:)` method to update the tableView. There's no need to update the datasource `items` as Realm `Results<T>` auto updates itself.

All is working well on iOS 13 and above, but when I tested it on iOS 12.4, iPhone 6 simulator, I had the same issue as you described in the question.

I figured out a solution while reading [this article](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781789133202/1/ch01lvl1sec13/uitableviewdelegate-and-interactions), it turned out that all you need to do is to call the completion handler provided in UIContextualAction.Handler after you have finished your updates, please refer to the code below:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, completion in
        Repository.shared.deleteItem(self.items![indexPath.row])  // delete item from Realm
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)  // update tableView
        completion(true) // notify the tableView that the swipe action has completed so now it can perform UI updates (this line is no longer needed on iOS 13+)
    }
    ...
}
```

This solved my problem, hope it works for you too.